# Data inserted successfully but not reflected in mongo DB using mean stack

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have created a mean stack application.
Am passing data from angular to node js.
In node js everything working fine and getting insert success message. But no data found in DB

**Node index.js**

```
// require('./app/route/dart.route.js')(app);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// make a connection
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dart', { useNewUrlParser: true });

// get reference to database
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

db.once('open', function () {
  console.log("Connection Successful!");
})
app.post('/dart_create', function (req, res) {
   console.log('Request body output '
     + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  try {
    db.collection("darts").insertMany(req.body);
    console.log("Data inserted successfully");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

**Node Console**

[image]

**Angular browser console**

[image]

**Mongo DB Screenshot**
[image]

Kindly help me to debug the issue. Where my data gone....

Answer (score 0):

Adding data in MongoDB is an asynchronuse process, use`.then` or use `async/await`

Using `async/await`

```
app.post('/dart_create', async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const result = await db.collection("darts").insertMany(req.body);
    console.log("Result", result);
    console.log("Data inserted successfully");
    return result;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
});
```

Insert many return response, like when inserted successfully

```
{
   "acknowledged" : true,
   "insertedIds" : []
}
```

check that veriable and lenght of `insertedIds` to cross check all are inserted or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your insertion operation to MongoDB is failing but your try and catch block isn't catching the error because the insert operation is an asynchronous operation.

So basically, there are two ways you can go about solving this problem:

Using `async/wait`

```
app.post('/dart_create', async function (req, res) {
   console.log('Request body output '
     + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  try {
    await db.collection("darts").insertMany(req.body);
    console.log("Data inserted successfully");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Using the `then` syntax for `promises`:

```
app.post('/dart_create', function (req, res) {
   console.log('Request body output '
     + JSON.stringify(req.body));
  db
    .collection("darts")
    .insertMany(req.body)
    .then(() => {
      console.log("Data inserted successfully");
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    })
});
```

You should be able to catch the error and resolve your issue from there.